# how to solve “Hyper-V is not enabled”

Tags: windows, hyper-v, c#

I am using the mobile emulator to run a UWP demo，but I get the error: the emulator requires the Hyper-V feature of Windows. Enable Hyper-V and then try running the emulator again.
However, I can run the demo on my local machine and tablet PC emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V requires hardware virtualization to be enabled.

*If you happen to use a Mac boot into OSX and back to Windows.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to "Turn Windows features on or off" and turning on Hyper-V. That's a good first step. If it doesn't let you, then that's when you look your specific computer model up online and see if it has hardware virtualization and then go to your BIOS and look for the setting to enable it.

If you want to provide specific system information, perhaps we could talk specifically to your system/BIOS.